# Removing duplicates from a 4D list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm working with a 4D list and I'm trying to remove some duplicate inner lists, I have done something, but it's not exactly working, here is my code.

```
mylist = [[[], [[4, 3], [4, 3]], [[3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]], [[[4, 2], [2, 3]], [[4, 3], [4, 3]], [[3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]]]

final_list = []
    for i in mylist:
        current = []
        for j in i:
            for k in j:
                for l in zip(k, k[1:]):
                    if list(l) not in current:
                        current.append(list(l))
        final_list.append(current)

print(final_list)

final_list = [[[3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]], [[3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]]
```

So instead of removing elements I append the values that are the same. This should be my desired output

```
        #Here I remove the duplicate  [4,3]                               #And here
                      !                                                       !  
                      v                                                       v

final_list = [[[], [[4, 3]], [[3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]], [[[4, 2], [2, 3]], [[4, 3]], [[3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]]]
```

I think there should be an easy way, too many nested for loops, so any help would be appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicates from the lists that are the deepest in the collection or you want to delete identical lists on all levels?

Comment: Only in the deepest, the pairs one, not the other levels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this with `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
final_list=[[list(sbls for sbls,_ in itertools.groupby(sbls)) for sbls in ls] for ls in mylist]
```

---

Same as:

```
final_list=[[[sbls[i] for i in range(len(sbls)) if i == 0 or sbls[i] != sbls[i-1]] for sbls in ls] for ls in mylist]
```

---

Both outputs:

```
final_list
[[[], [[4, 3]], [[3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]],
 [[[4, 2], [2, 3]], [[4, 3]], [[3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]]]
```

---

It can be done manually as well, with for loops, similar to your original approach:

```
flist=[]
for ls in mylist:
    new_ls=[]
    for sbls in ls:
        new_sbls = []
        for elem in sbls:
            if elem not in new_sbls:
                new_sbls.append(elem)
        new_ls.append(new_sbls)
    flist.append(new_ls)
```

Comment: Thank you for the long answer! I can see what I was doing wrong, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) twice in order to reduce your list to a two-dimensional list. Now you can search for duplicates (e.g. by using `count` to count the numbers of occurrences. There are many solutions for this). Once you found all your duplicate entries, iterate over your original list and remove all but one occurrence of the duplicates:

```py
import itertools

flat_list = itertools.chain(*itertools.chain(*mylist))

# TODO find duplicates in flat list
duplicates = ...

# TODO remove all duplicates from the original list
```

Comment: Not the best and by far not the most performant way to do this